# Redirecting stdin to a file with the file content being reflected on the console

Tags: bash, shell

Is there a way to redirect stdin to a file but at the same time reflect what's being read from the file on the console?

Update: I'm trying to redirect the contents of a file to the standard input of a program, but at the same time reflect the standard input and output of that program on the console. I've tried something like:

```
echo "$(cat inputfile)" | tee /dev/tty | ./program
```

which doesn't seem to be the right thing to do.

Comment: Type man tee and that should help. You could just do tee filename in the simplest.

Comment: `cat inputfile && cat inputfile | ./program` or `cat inputfile && TEST < inputfile`

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing seems fine to me.  You can avoid the crazy stuff, though:

```
tee /dev/tty <inputfile | ./program
```

`echo $(cat)` will coincidentally squish whitespace. I assume you used this by mistake, but if that's what you genuinely want to accomplish, try

```
tr -s '\n\t' ' ' <inputfile | tee /dev/tty | ./program
```